# Error loading vendor cdn script due to duplicate babel-polyfill instances

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

I'm attempting to load a script for an affiliate service (https://linkmink.com).

I'm loading this in the head section before the vue-cli scripts are loaded:

`myapp/public/index.html`:

```
<script src="https://cdn.linkmink.com/lm-js/2.2.0/lm.js"></script>
```

But when I try to load the app in the browser, I get the following error:

> Error: only one instance of babel-polyfill is allowed

So assuming the vendor can't remove their babel-polyfill dependency, how can I remove it from my vue-cli app to prevent duplicate instances? Is there any possibility that